# PHP can't write despite having permissions

Tags: php, linux, permissions, prestashop

I'm trying to set up prestashop but can't get php to recognize write permissions.
I'm getting the following error

> You need to grant write permissions for PHP on the following directory: /usr/share/nginx/presta

output of ls -la

```
total 75960
drwxr-xr-x 2 http http     4096 Oct  5 23:45 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root     4096 Oct  5 20:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http   690272 Sep 14 12:00 index.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http      441 Jun 15 11:32 Install_PrestaShop.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http 77073848 Sep 14 12:00 prestashop.zip
```

I'm using nginx on arch here's http server config

```
server {
    # Ipv4
    listen 82 ssl;

    # IPv6
    # listen [::]:80;

    # SSL Ipv4 & v6
    # listen 443 ssl http2;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # Your SSL Certificates, don't forget to take a look at Certbot (https://certbot.eff.org)
    # ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
            ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
            ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:1m;
            ssl_session_timeout       5m;
            ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:AES128-SHA:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # Do not forget to create this file before with OpenSSL : "openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048"
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # [REQUIRED EDIT] Your domain name goes here
    server_name domain.tld;

    # [REQUIRED EDIT] Absolute path to your website root on the filesystem
        root /usr/share/nginx/presta;

    index index.php;

    # Redirect 404 errors to prestashop
    error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

    # Gzip Settings, convert all types.
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;

    # Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
    # gzip_comp_level    5;
    # gzip_min_length    256;

    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    # HSTS (Force clients to interact with your website using HTTPS only)
    # For enhanced security, register your site here: https://hstspreload.org/
    # WARNING: Don't use this if your site is not fully on HTTPS!
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" preload; always;

    # Cloudflare / Max CDN fix
    location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff(?:2)?)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    # Force pdf files to be downloaded
    location ~* \.pdf$ {
        add_header Content-Disposition Attachment;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }

    # Force files in upload directory to be downloaded
    location ~ ^/upload/ {
        add_header Content-Disposition Attachment;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }

    # Do not save logs for these
    location = /favicon.ico {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # [REQUIRED EDIT] if you are using multiple languages
    # rewrite ^/fr$ /fr/ redirect;
    # rewrite ^/fr/(.*) /$1;

    # Images
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

    # AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
    rewrite ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

    # Web service API
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;

    # Installation sandbox
    rewrite ^(/install(?:-dev)?/sandbox)/(.*) /$1/test.php last;

    # without this line nginx seo url not working.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    # [REQUIRED EDIT] Change this block to your admin folder
    location /admin-dev/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /admin-dev/index.php last;
        }
    }


    # File security
    # .htaccess .DS_Store .htpasswd etc
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
    # Source code directories
    location ~ ^/(app|bin|cache|classes|config|controllers|docs|localization|override|src|tests|tests-legacy|tools|translations|travis-scripts|vendor|var)/ {
        deny all;
    }
    # vendor in modules directory
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/vendor/ {
        deny all;
    }
    # Prevent exposing other sensitive files
    location ~ \.(yml|log|tpl|twig|sass)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Prevent injection of php files
    location /upload {
        location ~ \.php$ {
            deny all;
        }
    }
    location /img {
        location ~ \.php$ {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    # PHP FPM part
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Verify that the file exists, redirect to index if not
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name /index.php$uri&$args =404;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;

        # Environment variables for PHP
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include       fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # [REQUIRED EDIT] Connection to PHP-FPM - choose one
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 30s;

        # In case of long loading or 502 / 504 errors
        # fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        # fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        # fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        client_max_body_size 16M;
    }
}
```

PHP is running under the `http` user, confirmed that by running a file containing `` <?php echo `whoami`; ?> `` from the browser.

A simple php file using fwrite also fails.

And yes I tried changing permissions of all files and dirs to 777/666 to check if maybe somehow php ran under different user but it did nothing.

Comment: have you checked if the parent directories to ```/usr/share/nginx/presta``` is executable by user ```http```? have you tried logging in as user ```http``` then writing to said file/directory? e.g.: ```sudo su http```

Comment: Yes, all the parent directories have the execute permission for user, group and other. User http has it's shell set to /sbin/nologin but when I changed it to bash I was able to create a new file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why install PrstaShop there?
It is customary to install it in the webserver root which for linux bases servers is either /var/www (/var/www/html) or chrooted user directories.
PHP will have no issue there.

Comment: Because I have other webserver running there. The directory I want to install it in has all the required permissions and I'm not running SELinux which would stop PHP from having write access.